# Miniconda with dockerfile, how to use the conda environment

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

Goal: create a docker image from miniconda that will install all my dependencies and then run some commands for django and other packages. Also every time someone bin/bash into the container it should start with those packages available without me adding an entrypoint and do env hacks there.

```
Dockerfile:
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
ADD environment.yml /code/
WORKDIR /code/
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml  # successful
RUN python test/manage.py 8000  # fails, no dependencies like pandas installed
```

But now I'm stuck, say I want to run some commands in the created environment:

```
RUN python manage.py runserver
```

it doesn't run it in my environment.

Some ugly hacks here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/89 that don't actually work because you're using a new shell session when you enter a container or do another RUN command so you have to concatenate the commands with && (ugly).

Ideally I want to install all my conda packages **globally** from environment.yml but apparently I can't do that.

Comment: Hi Claudiu, are you sure your Dockerfile works? Your last command should refer the environment file as /code/environment.yml. Can you post the docker command you run?

Comment: The linked issue is still open.

Comment: @Mihai yes, sorry, I have a `WORKDIR /code/` that I didn't include it for brevity

Comment: Can you please edit the post and add the complete Dockerfile? Also the "RUN conda ..." line, is it running successful?

Comment: @Mihai updated, yes, runs successful

Comment: From a docker perspective this should work. I am not familiar with conda or python but running a test and looking on internet I see that you should also activate your environment before using it (conda activate <env name>). I am sure you know more than me but can you try to add this step or do you already know it is not needed? Otherwise can you pass me the files I need to run this on my own and test it?

Comment: @Mihai I am activating the environment, but I see that docker requires me to activate the environment every time I bash into the container or I run a `RUN` command, which is not ideal, but it is a solution, thanks

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga This seems weird... We can chat about it so that we don't make this a too long discussion. Or maybe you can update the post with your latest Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell docker where is the python version managed by conda, and inside docker this is done with `conda run`

```
conda run --no-capture-output -n myenv python run.py
```

Source
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/